# If else statement with 4 outcomes but only 2 seems to work

Tags: java, if-statement

So I'm working on my first project on programming at my new study. Never tried programming anything before. I want to make it able to choose between 4 different outcomes and a default function but it only seems to be able to choose between the if statement and the second else if. What have I done wrong?

```
private void userStandby () {                                                             

    System.out.println("What do you want to set your membershipstatus to");                       
    System.out.println("1) Active \n2) Standby");                                              
    int newchange = input.nextInt();                                                          

    ((Medlem) currentUser).setStatus(newchange);                                             

    if (((Medlem) currentUser).getStatus() == 1 && newchange == 1) {                         
        System.out.println("Your membership is already active");                                                                                                                
    } else if (((Medlem) currentUser).getStatus() == 1 && newchange == 2)  {                  
        System.out.println("Your membership is now on standby");                              
    } else if (((Medlem) currentUser).getStatus() == 2 && newchange == 2) {                   
        System.out.println("Your membership is already on standby");                      
    } else if (((Medlem) currentUser).getStatus() == 2 && newchange == 1) {                    

        System.out.println("Your membership is now active");                                   
   } else                                                                                     
        System.out.println("Please write 1 or 2");                                  

   userStandby();                                                                           

}
```

Comment: Style advice: do not cast to `(Medlem)` 5 separate times. Before the first instance where you cast, create a new variable like `Medlem medlem = (Medlem) currentUser`

Comment: that depends on the variables you compare

Comment: to add to Michael 's advice, also don't perform checks two times, if you can do it in one with nested if's

Comment: You are setting the user status before doing any comparisons, so `currentUser.getStatus()` will **always** be equal to `newChange`...

Comment: General advice: stepping through your code with a debugger would help you spot the error pretty fast. You might want to learn how to do that for future development.

Answer (score 8):

```
((Medlem) currentUser).setStatus(newchange);
```

implies that `((Medlem) currentUser).getStatus() == newchange`, so of course only two of the branches can be executed - the one where both of them are equal to 1 and the one where both of them are equal to 2.

Perhaps your intention was to call `setStatus` after the if-else-if-..-else statements.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code there is no scenario in which the value of `(Medlem) currentUser).getStatus()` and `newchange` will be different. This is because once the value of `newchange` is set, in the very next line you are setting the  same value to `(Medlem) currentUser)`

Thus you are seeing only two out of the four possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the status of your current user above the `if` statements. This means, that the `getStatus()` methods always return the same as `newchange`.

Try to move that line *below* your if statements, so that the information about the previous status is not lost and can be used in your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the old status once and check it :

```
int oldChange = ((Medlem) currentUser).getStatus();
((Medlem) currentUser).setStatus(newchange);  
if (oldChange  == 1 && newchange == 1) {                         
     System.out.println("Your membership is already active");                             
 } else if (oldChange  == 1 && newchange == 2) {                  
  System.out.println("Your membership is now on standby");                              
 } else if (oldChange  == 2 && newchange == 2) {                   
    System.out.println("Your membership is already on standby");                      
 } else if (oldChange  == 2 && newchange == 1) {                    
     System.out.println("Your membership is now active");                                   
 } else {                                                                                    
    System.out.println("Please write 1 or 2");  
 }
```

Comment: I'd recommend a nested if statement. The outer if, checks oldChange. This will be more readable and more efficient.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong it'll have redundant else with `Please write 1 or 2`, and I don't like to use `switch` in such case

Comment: Thanks, guys, first post in here and I'm so surprised by how fast I got an answer. Really impressed by the community. It's working as intended now

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code :

```
 ((Medlem) currentUser).setStatus(newchange);
```

You are setting currentUser's status to newChange. Which means the status and newChange are always the same, either 1, or 2.

Therefore, when you check for the status of currentUser while also checking newChange, you will only ever get through these if statements :

```
 if (((Medlem) currentUser).getStatus() == 1 && newchange == 1) {                         
     System.out.println("Your membership is already active");                             

 } 
  else if (((Medlem) currentUser).getStatus() == 2 && newchange == 2) {                   
    System.out.println("Your membership is already on standby");                      
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and simplify the code -->

```
    int newchange = input.nextInt();
    // you don't need to call this method every time you want to check something 
    int currUserStatus = ((Medlem) currentUser).setStatus(newchange);

    //Check currUserStatus 1
    if (currUserStatus == 1) {
        // check change
        if (newchange == 1) {
            // code
        } else if (newchange == 2) {
            //code
        }

    // check currUserStatus 2
    } else if (currUserStatus == 2) {
        // check change
        if (newchange == 1) {
            // code
        } else if (newchange == 2) {
            //code
        }
```

Hope it helps.